# Notification badge not clearing on iOS (using Cordova Marketing Cloud SDK plugin)

Tags: ios

We're running into an odd issue with using the MarketingCloudSDK Cordova plugin on iOS. We're able to successfully receive a PUSH notification that appears in the notification shade, and we can see the badge appear on our app icon as well.

However, when you tap the app icon, the notification badge is never cleared. I have [followed the only instructions](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin/blob/master/ios_push.md) I can find to get the PUSH notification working but there just isn't anything regarding clearing the badge.

We're using the Ionic app development framework - any guidance anyone could provide on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben.